# MicroProfile Rest Client vs Vertx Client in Quarkus

Tags: rest, client, vert.x, quarkus, microprofile

I noticed two guide on Rest Client: MicroProfile and Vertx. 
Since MicroProfile   supports asynchronous, what is the advantage of using  Vertx-based  Rest Client ?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some differences between the 2 approaches:

- the MicroProfile Rest Client is not non-blocking. The Vert.x web client is.
- if the rest of your code uses RX Java, the Vert.x client has a neat RX Java API.
- the MicroProfile Rest Client is using an annotation-driven approach, the Vert.x client is API-driven

So it depends on your use case. Of course, you can combine both in the same application.

Answer (score 1):

https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client

MicroProfile restclient is async and non-blocking as well. Just use CompletionStage as return type.